# What does "mfgpctt" mean in version number of font

Tags: fonts, typography, font-design, file-conversion

I noticed in the metadata of many fonts that they have a strange version record. In at least a few fonts from different families, I found the string "mfgpctt v4.4", with the numbers sometimes being different.

Is it really the version number of the font or information about program in which it was generated?